# Can a rj-45 cable's joint be made by a pair of rj-45?

Tags: rj-45

I am interested to know if that if two network cables are to be joined together,can we use a pair of rj-45 to connect them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[yes](http://www.google.com/search?q=rj45+coupler&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#q=rj45+coupler&num=10&hl=en&newwindow=1&client=firefox-a&hs=uqw&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&prmd=ivs&source=univ&tbs=shop:1&tbo=u&ei=lzbLTMTTJYj2swOx3ojSDg&sa=X&oi=product_result_group&ct=title&resnum=3&ved=0CE4QrQQwAg&fp=b7b968c575c3858f)

Comment: Just make sure you get a straight-through coupler, otherwise it will modify the pinout.

Comment: And is there a decrease in the speed?

Comment: @fahad: No, there won't be.

Comment: You should be fine so long as the total length is within specifications for cat5 (or whatever you are using.)

Comment: I have several RJ-45 couplers fitted at work with no problems at all. Saves relaying long runs of cable when a cabinet is moved. You can pay a premium price at places like BlackBox or buy a cheapie at somewhere like Novatech.

Answer (score 0):

Two RJ-45s can't be connected together.  They're both "male" connectors.

Something like this product (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812999142&Tpk=cat5%20coupler) would work.  Unfortunately, it's not much cheaper than just buying a longer patch cable.  (I have no affiliation with Newegg.)

Comment: Can't we just join the wires together?I have seen that it works.With a decrease in speed?

Comment: @fahad: It would be difficult to do it just by splicing the wires -- the wires themselves need to be the exact same length, and you can't untwist the wires in the cable or you will put it out of spec -- the twisted nature of the cable is one of the ways external interference is handled in-cable. You would also need to ensure that there was not large blobs of metal or soldier hanging off the cables, as that would increase the capacitance and inductance of the cable, which would (again) put it out of spec.

Comment: But ultimately it would probably work, in a pinch. Better, use a coupler - they're about GBP £0.50. Best, replace the cable.